# Azure Active Directory Graph API Authorization Failed to get Groups for user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authorization, azure-active-directory

First I used the following to implement role based access:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/749588/Role-Based-Access-Control-with-Azure-Active-Direct

It is working FINE with **localhost url** when I deployed I got following error:

**The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
[ActiveDirectoryAuthenticationException: AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.
Trace ID: b672d4b0-eccc-45b2-97e8-0f9c8c916aea
Correlation ID: dcb4bad8-e449-4919-832d-0791eef24570**

To fix, I created a new application in Azure directory and give all permissions and updated web.config with the Client ID and Password of the app.

But still get the same error. So decided to do it manually:

used following code

```
  string tenantId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(TenantIdClaimType).Value;

        // Get a token for calling the Windows Azure Active Directory Graph
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, LoginUrl, tenantId));
        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AppPrincipalId, AppKey);
        AuthenticationResult assertionCredential = authContext.AcquireToken(GraphUrl, credential);
        string authHeader = assertionCredential.CreateAuthorizationHeader();
```

and

To get all users

```
    private static readonly string GraphAllUsersUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users?api-version=2013-04-05";
 string requestUrl = String.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                GraphAllUsersUrl,
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId));

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

It is working fine.

Now to get all groups of a user:

```
       private static readonly string UserGroupsUrl = "https://graph.windows.net/{0}/users/{1}/memberOf?api-version=2013-04-05";
 string requestUrl2 = String.Format(
               CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
               UserGroupsUrl,
               HttpUtility.UrlEncode(tenantId),
               HttpUtility.UrlEncode(ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.Name)
               );
      HttpRequestMessage request2 = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl2);
                request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", authHeader);
                HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.SendAsync(request2);
                string responseString2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

it throws the same Authorization error.

On searching, I found to set something in manifest file, I did but no luck.

Comment: Brij, can you repro and provide the same authorization error information, but this time can you also provide the timestamp provided with the error please?  That might help us track down the issue.  Although I don't think it's an issue, you should try using the latest version of Graph API (api-version=1.6).